# Epsilon delta proof of a quadratic reciprocal

Tags: limits, epsilon-delta

I'm trying to prove the following limit:
$$\lim _{x\to 3}\frac{18}{x^2}=2$$

I'm not seeing how I can relate δ with ε, here's what I have done:$$\left|\frac{18}{x^2}-2\right|=\left|\frac{18-2x^2}{x^2}\right|=2\left|\frac{9-x^2}{x^2}\right|=2\frac{\left|x+3\right|}{\left|x^2\right|}\left|x-3\right|$$

I'm not sure how to continue to relate $\delta$ with $\varepsilon$ .

Comment: Bound $|x-3|$ (for example, say it is at least less than 1) and use that to find the extremes of $x+3$ and $x^2$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g*., [basic help on mathjax notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), [main meta site math tutorial](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68388/there-should-be-universal-latex-mathjax-guide-for-sites-supporting-it/70559#70559), and [equation editing how-to](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto).

Comment: @DavidP If I'm understanding you correctly, I have to use |x - 3| < δ, pick a value for δ, turn it into -δ < x - 3 < δ and then find the extremes of x + 3 and x^2?

Comment: Yes, but pick a value that separates it enough from other zeros of your expression.